# Sum and Difference of two Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_1$and  $P_2$ be two projections of a vector space V, then which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

1. $P_1+P2 $ is a projection if $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$

   2. $P_1-P2 $ is a projection if $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$
   3. $P_1+P2 $ is a projection
   4. $P_1-P2 $ is a projection

Comment: This would appear to be an early question in a text concerning linear projections. Are you having trouble understanding this question?

Comment: Sir,my answer is option 4 but I don't know about whether mine is right or wrong

Comment: Start by writing down the definition of *projection* and then try to apply it to the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $P$ is projection $\iff $ $P^2=P$

for $(1)$, $(P_{1}+P_{2})^2= P_{1}^2+ P_1 P_2+ P_2P_1+ P_2^2$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: If I do similarly option two also correct???

Comment: Yeah yeah I got it sir, thank u so much